# Не работает относительный путь к файлу в python

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть папка Files, в ней лежит два файла- file_reader.py, который должен открывать второй файл, и, собственно второй файл pi_digits.txt. В коде не работает относительный путь к файлу, но работает абсолютный путь, в названии файла ошибок нет. Почему так? Вот код:

```
with open('pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
print(contents)
```

Если это имеет значение, то пишу в vs code

Comment: Запустил у себя, всё работает как надо. Эта ошибка - невоспроизводимая.

Comment: А каким образом вы запускайте Python файл?

Comment: Текущий каталог - это не обязательно тот, в котором лежит скрипт. Он может быть любой. Хотите, чтобы это был каталог с вашим скриптом - в явном виде переходите в этот каталог, прежде чем запускать скрипт.

Comment: Python файл запускаю прямо в vs code через расширение code runner и напрямую через run - run without debugging, результат все время одинаковый. До этого у меня не было никаких проблем например с импортом модулей, которые также лежали в одной папке, но вот с открытием файла почему то проблемы

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в начало файла код `import os; print(os.getcwd())` - и узнаете, какой же каталог текущий получается.

Comment: os.getcwd() вернула другой каталог, на 2 уровня выше. Теперь я еще больше не понимаю ничего( разве относительный путь к файлу не должен работать именно относительно файла который в данный момент выполняется, то бишь моего скрипта? Прошу прощения если задаю очень глупые вопросы, я только учусь(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Путь считается относительно того в какой папке вы находились при запуске программы `os.getcwd()`.

Относительно файла нужно считать вручную.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

with open( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Files','pi_digits.txt')) as file_object:
```

`__file__` - путь к этому файлу

Answer (score 0):

Вероятная причина ошибки в том, что относительный путь считаете от воторого файла, к третьему, а нужно от первого к третьему.

```
folder:|file1
       |file2
        dir1|file3
            |file4
```

Если исполняемый файл 1 вызывает файл 3 в котором прописан относительный путь к файлу 4 как `./file4` то будет ошибка, так как текущий рабочий каталог исполняемого файла folder, а не folder/dir. Относительный путь должен считатся не от файла в котором он прописывается, а от текущей рабочей директории `os.getcwd()`, в большинстве случаев она совпадает с директорией исполняемого скрипта, но при вызове исполняемого скрипта из консоли она будет текущей рабочей директорией консоли.

Answer (score 0):

По всей видимости, относительный путь я указал неправильно и он должен был начинаться на пару каталогов выше. Всем спасибо за помощь

Comment: но не обязан. если вы запустите программу по ярлыку с рабочего стола, то относительный путь будет начинаться от рабочего стола.

Comment: @eri, в принципе есть возможность в ярлыке указать рабочую папку. Но надежнее конечно брать путь скрипта и от него вычислять путь к нужному файлу, как у вас в ответ.